# VS 2019 (Visual studio) Linux makefile project - 'No such file or directory' when compiling from windows

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, visual-studio-2019

I have a makefile projects on Linux (CentOS).
The projects are compiled fine when compile from the Linux terminal.
I added those projects to visual studio 2019.
The connection is fine (files are copied to linux).
I defined the remote working folder and project folder, and type of project (Makefile- static library).
But, when compiling from the VS it is complaining he can't find include files (personal files from other projects).
The folders and files ofcourse exists both on the windows and the Linux. The VS intelisense finds the files.
I had environment variable that holds path and used in the Makefile.
I changed the Makefile to have direct path and still files weren't found.
I added prebuild event to echo the environment variable and it write it is not set.
What else can be done/defined/configured....?
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Thanks for another different case which suggested to look at the command sent to the linux and there I saw the problem was actually that in some places of the path I missed replacing the '\' with '/' (This is difference between windows and Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for another different case which suggested to look at the command sent to the linux.
I saw that the problem was actually that I missed replacing some of the '' with '/' in some of the paths.
(This is difference between windows and Linux).
i.e: in windows path:

C: \Folder1\Folder2\Folder3     **------>** /home/user/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3

[this is on the Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfazF.png)

Comment: can't see where to mark it as 'Answered'.
I added an answered, not as comment, and do not see some place to change status or something.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. You could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.